# SSRS BIDS 2008 Bubble Chart - Bubble Marker Size

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, bubble-chart

I have a bubble chart and I want to have the bubble size adjusted based on a field called [Weight]. The larger the weight the larger I want my bubble to be. The weights range from 5-65. I don't have a preference on the range for the size of the bubbles as long as they increase in size.

How do I set my ChartSeries>CustomAttribute>BubbleMaxSize and Bubble Min Size? I don't know if It should be an expression or a set value.

How do I then set up my Size field with a function to make the bubbles bigger the bigger the weight?

Comment: What are your issues with the default setup for a bubble chart, i.e. what are the issues when you set the **Chart Series** -> **Bubble Size** property to `=Fields!Weight.Value`?

Comment: When I change the series Size it defaults to [SUM(CategoryWeight)], so I change it to =Fields!Weight.Value, but it did not adjust.

Comment: Now that I have certain bubbles bigger than others do you know how to get the smaller bubbles to go to the front and larger back? Is it even possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Bubble chart expression and write there an expression based upon the size of the rane so that it will dynamically increase the size of bubble.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution to the problem. First you need go to Series>Highlight Series and view the Properties window. Under General>Custom  Attributes>BubbleMaxSize and BubbleMinSize need to be adjusted to fit your maximum bubble size you want to allow.  For me I set my Bubble Size Max=45 and BubbleMinSize=1.

Then, I went to series and adjusted my size =Fields!CategoryWeight.Value and it gives me the result of different bubble sizes for differenty weightings.

Thanks for all the help.